# Execute Batch file in many PC's

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a script in a batch file contain function to execute a video from folder under the server , this script work properly , but the problem that i have more than 100 PC's that i should open on them this training video, i add this batch file in the Task Scheduler.
I have two questions here :

1. Is there any idea to avoid connecting to all those PC's to upload the script and open this video ?
2. If i decide to change this video i want to refresh the script under the batch file after 1 hour
3. Here's the Code :

   ```
   @echo off
   if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 
   color 0A
   TITLE RUN Videos Script
   setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "STR=RUN Videos SCRIPT ^!"
   set "SIZE=50"


   if not exist "C:\Users\TV_Caddy_IR1\Desktop\vid" mkdir C:\Users\TV_Caddy_IR1\Desktop\vid
   xcopy /y /f "\\server01\backup$\Formations Video\*.mp4" 
   "C:\Users\TV_Caddy_IR1\Desktop\vid"
   START "" "vlc.exe" --fullscreen C:\Users\TV_Caddy_IR1\Desktop\vid
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the video to a network share, and your PC's have the network drive added already. If you have a Windows network with Active Directory, then you can use group policy to add the network drive, and also at startup to open VLC player and start playing the video if you wish.